# How to restart syncing of the Dropbox folder on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, dropbox

I'm having problems with Dropbox, as it is constantly syncing data and eating up my CPU.

How do I restart syncing of the Dropbox folder? I guess there must be a metadata file that I should delete, but I'm not sure where to look.

Mac OS X 10.7.3 --
Dropbox 1.2.52

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem a long time ago.

Your version is outdated and the fact that it didn't self-update is a significant issue as and of itself...

Try manually deleting the Dropbox.app and installing a fresh copy downloaded from their site - that did the trick for me.

Comment: PS if you're feeling a bit adventurous, go for the 1.3.34 forum build and sync some photos to get an extra free 3GB of space...

Comment: I have since solved the issue of syncing, some files were failing to sync (for some reason), and blocked syncing the rest. I will check the version, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

When mine recently quit syncing, I closed it (click on the toolbar icon, close), and restarted it (/Applications/Dropbox), works just fine.  May not be your problem, but worth a try.

Comment: Works for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

Mac OS 10.10.3
DropBox 3.6.7

- try going to preferences->account->selective sync
- remove the problematic folder
- let DropBox sync your choice
- add the folder back